# How can I correct this query in CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a query that I'm trying to create in CakePHP 2.5.5.

My database has two tables that are of interest to this question. The first being `Members`, and the second being `MemberStateLicenses`. `Members` is information on that member, and `MemberStateLicenses` is a table of licenses that member holds in various states.

This paste contains the array being built for the query before it is passed to the `find` method: http://pastebin.com/kM18nKpr

I am attempting to query for any member that resides in a state, or is licensed in a state. For example:

- `Select all members who live in Michigan, or are licensed in Ohio`
- `Select all members who live in Maryland, or are licensed in Maryland`

This is the scenario in which this is failing:

- John lives in Ohio.
- John does not have any licenses.
- I query for anyone who lives in Ohio OR is licensed in Ohio.
- No results, even though John does live in Ohio.
- I give john a license in California, and repeat the same Ohio/Ohio query. John is returned, as expected.

So this query is failing when the member has no records in MemberStateLicenses.

My question is this:

- What is wrong with my query that is excluding any member that has no `MemberStateLicenses` record?

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste the SQL that CakePHP generates? can you paste the actual code that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What is wrong with my query that is excluding any member that has no MemberStateLicenses record?*

You have an inner join between Member and MemberStateLicenses, which means that only records from Member that have at least one corresponding record in MemberStateLicenses can be chosen.

Try changing your inner joins to LEFT JOIN's.

Comment: This was exactly it. I didn't even consider the different joins - oops! Thank you very much!